# Random system hang when booting Ubuntu 19.04 with kernel 5.0.0

Tags: boot, kernel, acpi

I have been experiencing a few problems with my Ubuntu system (19.04) lately. I think it is related to the way the graphics interface is handled by kernel 5.0.0.

My computer is an Asus ZenBook 13 (bought a few months ago), my GPU is integrated (Intel HD Graphics, "Whiskey Lake").

The main problem is that I often have to (re)boot 20 or 30 times in order to start the system properly. Most of the time, it just gets stuck on the purple screen after the GRUB menu, and the fan runs at its maximal speed — the only way to stop the computer is to hold the power button. It seems to be completely random. I strongly suspect a graphics settings problem. *When Ubuntu boots correctly, I can use it without any problem* — everything seems to respond just fine.

I tried a complete reinstall of Ubuntu, but the problem persisted. For some reason, it has got even worse: now, even a Live USB drive won't load correctly (I just get a black screen after having selected an option [try Ubuntu / install Ubuntu], even in the safe graphics mode). I may have messed with xserver, but I have no idea regarding how to reinstall it in a clean way.

I have tried a lot of different potential solutions I found in other threads, including inserting `nomodeset` and various other commands in the GRUB commands (`acpi=off`...), but to no avail. Sometimes, `nomodeset` allows me to access the console mode — but, as I said, it seems to be completely random.

`dmesg -lerr` returns a lot of ACPI errors :

```
[    0.180812] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.180819] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.180823] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.180826] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.182034] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.182038] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.182040] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.182043] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.183243] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.183246] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.183249] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.183251] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.184456] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.184459] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.184462] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.184465] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.185665] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.185668] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.185671] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.185673] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.186873] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.186876] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.186879] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.186882] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.188082] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.188086] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.188088] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.188091] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.189291] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.189294] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.189297] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.189300] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.190500] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.190503] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.190506] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.190508] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.191706] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.191709] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.191712] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.191714] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.192959] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.192962] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.192965] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.192968] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.192972] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.192974] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.192977] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.192980] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193005] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193008] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193011] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193013] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193038] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193041] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193044] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193046] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193071] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193074] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193076] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193079] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193103] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193106] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193109] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193111] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193136] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193139] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193142] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193144] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193169] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193172] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.193174] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.193177] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.819098] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

I can't change any option in my BIOS menu, excepted secure mode and fast boot mode, which are already disabled.

I'm not an expert at all. I will happily provide all the logs you may ask me.

What could be the cause of this random booting success?

Answer (score 1):

I updated my BIOS from official asus website and the problem seems to be gone. Here is the [support website](https://www.asus.com/support) where you can download it for your model. Follow [these steps](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008859/) to flash the new BIOS into your PC.